# Is there a way to onChange a nested array in useState?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I have a very simple state that is an array of objects. The second object has an array of objects inside *that*. I am able to change the basic state using an onChange handler that works well. However when trying to access the nested data, and change it I have problems.

The display first of all is giving me object obJect. I usually would map this to get it working but the value is going inside a value property.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./style.css";
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { firstName: "Elon", lastName: "Musk" },
    {
      firstName: "Jeff",
      lastName: "Bezos",
      additionDetails: [{ worth: "Lots" }, { company: "Amazon" }],
    },
  ]);

  const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    const clonedData = [...data];

    clonedData[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;

    setData(clonedData);
  };
  console.log(Object.values(data[1].additionDetails[1]))
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((x, i) => {
        return [
          <input
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            value={x.firstName}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
          />,      

          <input
          type="text"
          name="Worth"
          value={x.additionDetails}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
        />,
          <br></br>,
        ];
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Why is `additionDetails` an array to begin with? imo It should be an object rather than an array of objects since each one contains a single property.

Comment: [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-elion-4k1vs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that not only addresses the problem at hand but also updates the state correctly instead of mutating the state objects directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet. Since the `additionDetails` is an array of items, use the `map` and have the `input` field for each item.

Update the handleChange accordingly, based on the nested level. (when arg `j` exist means, it is additionalDetails)

```js
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    { firstName: "Elon", lastName: "Musk" },
    {
      firstName: "Jeff",
      lastName: "Bezos",
      additionDetails: [{ worth: "Lots" }, { company: "Amazon" }],
    },
  ]);

  const handleChange = (e, i, j) => {
    const clonedData = [...data];

    if (j !== undefined) {
      clonedData[i]["additionDetails"][j][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    } else {
      clonedData[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    }

    setData(clonedData);
  };
  console.log(Object.values(data[1].additionDetails[1]));
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((x, i) => {
        return [
          <input
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            value={x.firstName}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
          />,

          x.additionDetails &&
            x.additionDetails.map((obj, j) => (
              <input
                type="text"
                name={Object.keys(obj)[0]}
                value={Object.values(obj)[0]}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i, j)}
              />
            )),
          <br></br>,
        ];
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"> Hello </div>
```

Comment: it says that i is undefined